# European roads toll cost

Tags: geospatial, cost

I'm looking for a dataset or an API that provides information about toll costs of european roads.

Something similar to ViaMichelin, that is what we are using now, but preferably free of charge.

Does somebody know some free dataset with this information?

I was thinking in OSM, but I do not know if offers this information.

Thanks

Comment: You could try doing a data pull from OSM of a road they mark as toll (or perhaps several) and check? However, since tolls change frequently, that information might not be included, or be dated if it is included.